# In Swift, should I run VC initialization code in prepareForSegue or in viewDidLoad if it is a viable option when maximizing frame rate is the goal?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, segue

**In Swift, is it better to run VC initialization code in prepareForSegue or in viewDidLoad if it is a viable option when maximizing frame rate is the goal?**

There are many times I can choose to setup a vc by passing in an enum that tells it what vc it is and sets itself up accordingly during viewDidLoad. I could instead directly setup these values inside of prepareForSegue minimizing the work during viewDidLoad. Assuming I need to run this code on the main thread, for the smoothest UI transition, which is preferable?

Comment: If you could post some sample code that would help a lot in answering your question.

Comment: I literally stated everything that has anything to do with my question in it. If I post sample code that wasn't perfect it would detract from the appropriate answer in my opinion... but now that I think about it, I might be able to come up with some sample code.

Comment: According to my limited knowledge the time will be same either you put in ViewDidLoad or in prepareForSegue however prepareForSegue will already setup your viewController but it won't effect the smoothness in transition as when outlets etc are all hooked then viewDidLoad is called which is earlier step of transition from one VC to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to strictly follow the principles of object oriented programing (and I advise you to) each object *must* take care of its own internal initialization and setting up and what not. As to which option is going to create a smoother user interface transition, it really does not matter since both options must run on the main thread (UIKit must run on the main thread).

Comment: I am very aware of this method being the best way to pass information between the viewControllers. My question was speaking from a maximizing the smoothness of the frame rate during the transition. I was wandering if for that purpose prepareForSegue > viewDidLoad or viewDidLoad > prepareForSegue........                                   **@A.Jam** `What does it being an optional have anything to do with my question?`

Comment: I'll upvote you because I appreciate you rewriting the answer and agree with your input, but I think there is room for a better answer from someone more knowledgeable out there to be found none the less.

Answer (score 0):

I realized after posting this question that it was in ignorance because both prepareForSegue and viewDidLoad happen prior to viewDidAppear and therefore will delay UI the same amount if the both have code in them that takes place on the main queue regardless of where the code is at. So there should be virtually no difference under nearly all conditions I can currently think of.